# Get the median of a Power BI measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, median

How can I calculate the median of a measure in Power BI DAX?

I have a measure [Total Utilization (%)], and I want to get its median. But it looks like I can only use Median for columns

Sample Dataset:

[image: Sample Dataset]

Comment: Median with respect to what? Some dates? Some categories? Post a very small example dataset in copiable format with expected result.

Comment: Employee Project Utilization Admin Utilization
John 88% 12%
Mike 90% 20%
Jerome 75% 40%
Allyza 89% 12%
Frank 60% 32%
Louis 93% 15%
Aaron 78% 29%
Claire 82% 9%
Dave 98% 18%


from this example. I created a measure [Total Utilization (%)] where I just add Project Utilization column and Admin Utilization column.

Comment: Now I want to get the Median of the measure that I created. How do you achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **measure**:

```
=
VAR T1 =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Table,
        Table[Employee],
        "Total Utilization", [Total Utilization (%)]
    )
RETURN
    MEDIANX (
        T1,
        [Total Utilization]
    )
```

Comment: Thanks man, I tried to use SUMMARIZE on this problem before but I didn't get the value I expected.
But your code works. Thanks a lot man.